# enable c++17 intellisense open folder visual studio ninja-clang

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

Using "`-Xclang -std=c++17`" I can build the executable, however I can't find what activates c++17 intellisense. I've tried many combinations as shown below and none seem to work

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.2)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
project(myapp)
add_compile_options("-Xclang" "-std=c++17")
add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
set_target_properties(myapp PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_compile_features(myapp PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <tuple>
namespace test1::test2 // red [qualified name is not allowed]
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{}

int main()
{
    auto[a, b] = std::pair<int, int>();
    //  ^^^^^^
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeSettings.json

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com//fwlink//?linkid=834763 for more information about this file.
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
      "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "variables": [
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER",
          "value": "clang-cl"
        },
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_C_COMPILER",
          "value": "clang-cl"
        },
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME",
          "value": "Windows"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As for December 2017 the only way to define the IntelliSense mode is via a `CppProperties.json` file in your root folder, which you can't combine with `CMakeSettings.json`.

See comments under [Visual C++ Team Blog: Customizing your Environment with Visual C++ and Open Folder](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/11/02/customizing-your-environment-with-visual-c-and-open-folder/):

> - justanotherdev: "... Would it be possible to inherit CppProperties includes from the project created via CMake? If so, getting Linux intellisense from the Windows CMake project would be a breeze and would solve a major issue with Linux (needing to specify all the includes for a project manually)."
>
>   - Will Buik [MSFT]: "This isn’t supported today. ..."

---

I've tried it and had no luck using something similar to what's recommended in the ["Open Folder projects in Visual C++" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/non-msbuild-projects).

1. I did go to `Project / Edit Settings / CppProperties.json`

   [image]
2. And inserted for testing into my configurations something like

   ```
   ...
       "compilerSwitches": "/std:c++17",
       "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x86"
   ...
   ```

   or any other of the supported modes:

   [image]

---

**References**

- [Developer Community: CMake C++ Project: Intellisense fails to parse included header directories](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80631/cmake-c-project-intellisense-fails-to-parse-includ.html)
- [Developer Community: Intellisense shows false errors with C++17 and CMake](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/43814/intellisense-shows-false-errors-with-c17-and-cmake.html)
- [GitHub Microsoft/VSLinux Issue #131: openfolder project ignores intelliSenseMode](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/131)
- [Visual C++ Team Blog: Use any C++ Compiler with Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/)

Answer (score 1):

To enable correct Intellisense for C++17, specify `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` in CMakeLists.txt before the project definition; no other configuration is needed. CMake will supply `-std=c++17` for clang-cl at build time.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.9.2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project ("test")
add_executable (Test "test.cpp" "test.h")
```

Verified in Visual Studio 2017 15.9.8

Comment: A detail: CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD has to be set before any target definition, not before the project definition.

Answer (score 0):

For my ARM/Linux development, I have added `"intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-arm"` into *CMakeSettings.json* as follows:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "cmakeToolchain": "arm-toolchain.cmake",
      "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-arm",
      "inheritEnvironments": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Release",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Release",
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "cmakeToolchain": "arm-toolchain.cmake",
      "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-arm",
      "inheritEnvironments": [],
      "variables": []
    }
  ]
}
```

and now Visual Studio correctly parses the source code.

All possible values are:

```
windows-msvc-x86
windows-msvc-x64
windows-msvc-arm
windows-msvc-arm64
android-clang-x86
android-clang-x64
android-clang-arm
android-clang-arm64
ios-clang-x86
ios-clang-x64
ios-clang-arm
ios-clang-arm64
windows-clang-x86
windows-clang-x64
windows-clang-arm
windows-clang-arm64
linux-gcc-x86
linux-gcc-x64
linux-gcc-arm
```